# Does Tahiti/French Polynesia offer VAT refund upon departure?

Tags: tahiti, vat

My hotel on Moorea includes a "VAT" charge of 13% on meals and spa receipts. Is it possible to get this amount refunded when I get to the airport for my return flight? If so, how? I found old (ten year plus) message board posts about it. The hotel front desk had no idea about it.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to get VAT back on your hotel bill. VAT refunds usually only apply to items that you're exporting, and then only if the retailer participates in the refund scheme (which they're not required to do)

Answer (score 3):

You can never reclaim VAT on anything you consumed in the country/territory. VAT refund schemes only apply to goods you export, and there are many conditions attached (minimum amount per transaction, minimum total amount, paperwork, etc.).

Meals and spas (as well as lodging, car rentals, tours, excursions, drinks, any services, etc.) are definitely not eligible for such schemes.